# Mail server settings always gets an error

Tags: icloud, email, gmail, imap

I wanted to add an iCloud address in gmail. I've entered everything correctly, hoping to show SMTP setting. But instead, it shows incorrect username and password, even also got stuck in the loading screen. I've entered the app specific password, correct imap server, correct user name based on [Mail server settings for iCloud email clients](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202304).
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want iCloud in gmail, the app allows a much simpler way of doing this. When adding a new account, just click the iCloud button instead of IMAP.

[image]

Then, enter your Apple ID, and go to [appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com) and create an app-specific password (see this [guide](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397)). Then enter that app-specific password into gmail, and that’s it (no servers, config, etcetera).

I think your IMAP method would work with an app-specific password, but the way stated above is much simpler.

Comment: I've used that, but this gets the issue

Comment: so your app-specific password is rejected by Gmail as incorrect (when you use the dedicated iCloud menu)?

Comment: Maybe, It stated that my Username or password is incorrect.

Comment: @pro70 I'm not sure why you blocked the domain of your email address but not the main part, but from what I can see, you are not typing in your "@icloud.com", "@mac.com", or "@me.com" email. You must not type in your main Apple ID into gmail, and instead type in this alias "iCloud" email. This can be found via appleid.apple.com > personal info > reachable at.

Comment: @pro70 was the issue resolved?